# unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm using AWS Code Build to build a Docker image from ECR. This is the Code Build configuration.
[image]
Here is the `buidspec.yml`

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region my-region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin my-image-uri
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t pos-drf .
      - docker tag pos-drf:latest my-image-uri/pos-drf:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push my-image-uri/pos-drf:latest
```

Now it's working up until the build command `docker build -t pos-drf .`
the error message I get is the following

```
[Container] 2022/12/30 15:12:39 Running command docker build -t pos-drf .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /codebuild/output/src696881611/src/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

[Container] 2022/12/30 15:12:39 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t pos-drf .. Reason: exit status 1
```

Now quite sure this is not a permission related issue.
Please let me know if I need to share something else.
UPDATE:
This is the `Dockerfile`

```
# base image
FROM python:3.8
# setup environment variable
ENV DockerHOME=/home/app/webapp

# set work directory
RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME

# where your code lives
WORKDIR $DockerHOME

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# copy whole project to your docker home directory.
COPY . $DockerHOME
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade
# RUN apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
# run this command to install all dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# port where the Django app runs
EXPOSE 8000
# start server
CMD python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Do you have `Dockerfile` file on your project?

Comment: Yes, let me update the question.

Comment: Error says `no such file or directory` means can not find your `Dockerfile`.

`Dockerfile` filename should be exactly `Dockerfile` not DockerFile or something else.

Comment: the file name is exactly Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I had the Dockerfile locally but hadn't pushed it.
CodeBuild worked successfully after pushing the Dockerfile.